# How to download tar file using pip

Tags: python, download, pip, tar, setuptools

I am trying to download `setuptools` using pip with the following command.

```
$ pip download --no-binary :all: setuptools
```

I am able to download the source code by using the command above; however, it comes in zip format rather than the tarball version.

The tarball is in the [python repositories](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#code-of-conduct)

Comment: Are you under Windows? Zip is the preferred format under Windows, and tar.gz for other platforms. You can use `wget` instead.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE I am on a Linux machine... It defaults to a zip file anyways